# Any way to trigger ReactDOM.createPortal other than through the render() function?

Tags: reactjs

As far as the docs are concerned, the only way to trigger the `ReactDOM.createPortal` is to run it inside the `render()` function of a stateful component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
      return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        this.props.children,
        domNode
      );
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to do this without the parent needing to be a stateful component?

Comment: How do you want to use it?Any specific case?

Comment: +1. I want to render a modal from a button's onClick() handler. I know I can modify the state of my component and have it render the modal as a portal, but I'm looking for a more generic solution.

Comment: i want to use it in a function that returns a promise which mounts the provided component and provides it with the resolve handler. unfortunately it never mounts anything inside the specified element. react and promises don't really play very well together.